# Using Entity Framework Core to generate classes for a sqlite table with an auto-incrementing primary key

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have a table in SQLite that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "LastSyncTime" 
( 
    `ID` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, 
    `SyncTime` TEXT NOT NULL, 
    `TableUpdated` TEXT NOT NULL 
)
```

I'm using the command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "DataSource=MyApp.sqlite;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite -OutputDir Models -force
```

to generate a `DbContext` and model classes.

Within `MyAppContext.cs` the table in question is generated as:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LastSyncTime>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasIndex(e => e.Id)
        .IsUnique();

     entity.Property(e => e.Id)
        .HasColumnName("ID")
        .ValueGeneratedNever();

    entity.Property(e => e.SyncTime).IsRequired();

    entity.Property(e => e.TableUpdated).IsRequired();
});
```

The problem is with `.ValueGeneratedNever()`, that annotation prevents Entity Framwork Core from being able to use the DB to assign IDs to newly created records.

With the result that starting with an empty table if I do:

```
db.LastSyncTime.Add(new LastSyncTime
{
    SyncTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("o"),
    TableUpdated = "TableName1"
});

db.LastSyncTime.Add(new LastSyncTime
{
    SyncTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("o"),
    TableUpdated = "TableName2"
});
```

It throws an exception on the second `Add()` because both records were created with an `ID` of 0, violating the `UNIQUE` constraint.

Getting the behavior I want - where each new record will get an ID assigned by the database automatically - requires changing the context to replace `ValueGeneratedNever()` with `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()`.

I've been attempting to keep my workflow with EF Core as close to the one I've used for years with the original Entity Framework, and am regenerating the context and model classes each time I made change to the database.

Is there a way to change the way `Scaffold-DbContext` generates the model, or are my choices to either manually correct the `DbContext` after each time it is updated, or to adopt a different workflow with EFCore entirely.  eg code first instead of database first.

I'm working in UWP, so I can't just switch to the original version of Entity Framework instead.

Comment: Use the generated model as a starting point. Customize it to fit your app. You wouldn't hesitate to change `MainPage.xaml`...

Comment: P.S. It's probably fixed in version 2.1.0-rc1-final. If not, would you mind [filing a bug](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/new)?

Comment: Database-first with SQLite seems a bit unusual, have you considered using a [Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/) workflow?

Comment: I'll double check when I'm back in the office tomorrow, but I believe it persisted when I tried the RC (I was messing with several other things at the same time, so I'm not 100% sure what state everything else was when I tried it). Switching to a migration workflow's possible if there's not a workaround available. I went DB first initially because it's the standard where I work with regular entity framework and SqlServer, I was hoping to keep the workflow as similar as possible to make it easier for anyone working on it after me; but the differences ended up large enough to be a moot point.

Comment: The issue with modifying the generated context is that the modifications don't persist across additional scaffolding calls; meaning that they'd need to be repeated every time I changed the DB schema and regenerated the model.

Comment: Sorry, I skimmed through the first time and missed that you were regenerating. You really want feature [#831](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/831) to persist your changes between updates. Please file a bug if it still repros; we should definitely fix it.

Comment: It's still broken in the RC build.  Bug submitted at:  https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11961

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to Microsoft](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11961) this has been fixed in EF Core 5.0.